# How to build a function which return a list which contains for each value from lst1, its position in list lst2

Tags: python-3.6

In Python 3.6 I get two lists from the input, and they are permutations of each other.

For example:

List 1 = [4,2,8,3]
List 2 = [2,4,3,8]

I want to get List 3 =  [1, 0, 3, 2] with the positions of all elements of list 1 in list 2.

I have already built the part that identifies whether the lists are permutations or not, then I have tried running loops of k in list 2, and appending list2[k] into a new list, but all I have got is confused results.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
List1 =  [4,2,8,3]
List2 =  [2,4,3,8]

def solve(a, b):
    result = []
    for x in range(0, len(a)):
        result.append(a.index(b[x]))
    return result

print solve(List1, List2)
```

Comment: Thanks... That one  worked.. But I din't quite understand why the lists names are aa and bb, but you define the function with (a, b)..

Comment: It's only name of variable, this is up to you. I've change it on List1, List2. I hope it is clearer now. Yea function is universal, just call it with two params :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd tackle your described problem:

```
List1 = [4, 2, 8, 3]
List2 = [2, 4, 3, 8]
List3 = []
for i in List1:
    List3.append(List2.index(i))

print(List3)
```

### Explanation

- With the for-statement I'm iterating through each value of List1.
- The List2.index() function returns the index of the given value in List2.
- With List3.append() I'm adding this value at the end of List3

[You can try it online here](https://tio.run/##JcsxCoAwDEDR2ZwiYwtF0DiI4A28gXQQWjFLLNpBT1/bur7PD288TqGUFr5jhzOug8He4GiQLBTsC2bJTtl/pIIW9vNCRhas9wRNbe0Wghen6t2yOP8o1hogXCyxMumUPg).

I hope this was able to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! It works and its a very simple solution. is list.index() a built-in function ?

Comment: Yes, *index* is method of *list class* and *list class* is build-in function.